# Reemplazar objeto dentro de un arraylist android

Tags: java, android

Tengo un arraylist que se llena con objetos provenientes de un scanner de bluetooth y lo muestro en un recycler. Lo que quiero hacer es que si existe que no lo agregue y solo reemplace su valor.

Este objeto trae la distancia mediante se mueve voy recibiendo una nueva, por ello necesito que se modifique el valor distancia solamente sin agregarlo nuevamente.

```
 for( int i =0; i < datos.size() ; i++ ){

     if (!datos.contains(beaconModel))
     {
          datos.add(beaconModel);
          adapter = new BeaconAdapter(datos, RangingActivity.this);
          recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
          recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
          Log.d("datos", datos.toString());
          datos.set(i,beaconModel);
      }
      else if (datos.contains(beaconModel)){
          datos.set(i,beaconModel);
          adapter = new BeaconAdapter(datos, RangingActivity.this);
          recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
          recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
          Log.d("datos", datos.toString());
      }
 }
```

Con esto he podido actualizar el dato pero me lo agrega mil veces xD.

`BeaconModel` es el objeto.
`datos` es el arraylist que contiene esos objetos.

Comment: Podrias pobrar a crear un hashmap en vez de un arraylist es mas comodo para controlar y sustituir el valor de un objeto

Comment: No lo haces bien. Deberías usar el datos.contains fuera del bucle for. Si lo contiene, entonces haces un bucle para buscarlo y cuando lo encuentras (con equals) actualizas su valor. Si el contains te devuelve false (no existe en el array) simplemente lo añades, aquí no te haría falte recorrer el array.

Answer (score 1):

Me imagino que lo que agregas tienen campos identificadores que los diferencian unos con otros, por ej : Nombres, Id, categorias etc etc. Seria lo más conveniente es buscar el ID o el campo identificador y reemplazar el valor que deseas. El codigo que dejaste te agrega mil veces tu valor, porque busca coincidencias de secuencias, me imagino que lo que agregas tiene un nombre y al encontrarlo lo agrega.

```
public class Dato {
     String nombre;
     String valor;
     int id;
}

//Metodo
for( int i =0; i < datos.size() ; i++ ){
    if(datos[i].id == beaconModel.id){
        datos[i].valor = beaconModel.valor;
    }
}
```

Me imagino algo asi, ya que no has dejado todo tu codigo asumo que podrias modificar tu modelo

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema que estás teniendo es por culpa de `if (!datos.contains(beaconModel))`

Creo que deberías sobreescribir el método `equals()` de tu **BeaconModel** para que compruebe si dos elementos son iguales de forma que tu creas conveniente, ya que según el [Javadoc para List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) el método `contains()` utiliza la función `equals()`

Por Ejemplo de la siguiente forma (me invento un poco la estructura de la clase BeaconModel a modo de ejemplo ya que no has puesto el código de ella):

```
public class BeaconModel 
{
    public int id; 
    public int distancia;   

    public BeaconModel (int x)
    {
        this.distancia = x;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object)
    {

        if (object != null && object instanceof BeaconModel )
        {
            return (this.id== ((BeaconModel ) object).id);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Este método se puede auto generar junto con el método `hashCode()` en el Android Studio haciendo **click derecho** dentro de tu clase, luego pulsas **Generate** y después **equals() and hashCode()** y sigues los pasos que te indique.